# Simple doubt about topological spaces constructed with the open sets of a metric space?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> [image]

I think the best route I could use is the following corollary:

> [image]

Because I proved these inequalities for the metrics presented in the problem but I am confusing in the following: If two metric spaces are topologically equivalent, do they give rise to the same topological space?

I think I could also use the following theorem and corollary:

> [image]

> [image]

But this looks like it would be a bit more complicated and I'm not sure they being metrically equivalent and hence, topologically equivalent implies they give rise to the same topological space.

Comment: The statement that two metrics are "topologically equivalent" is nothing but the statement that they give rise to the same topological space, no?

Comment: @HenryBosch I'm not sure, the book isn't too clear about this or I'm not reading it well.

Comment: I'm positive it does. Corollary 7.9 is saying that the identity map $(X,d) \to (X,d')$ (i.e. the function which maps each point to itself) is a homeomorphism between the topological spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$.

Comment: @HenryBosch Got it. I got a bit curious with the following: How do we write the open sets of one of the topological spaces in terms of the other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if two $(X,d), (X,d')$ obey the conditions of 7.9 the respective topologies on $X$ induced by $d$ resp. $d'$ are the same: they give rise to the same topologies space $(X,\mathcal{T})$. This could also be the case without the metrics obeying that condition (this condition is stating a "uniform equivalence" of the metrics) but it *is* a sufficient condition and indeed one that would work for the alternate metrics on Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ from your initial problem. It's a common enough situation to have a special theorem for that situation.

The final two statements are just a reformulation of being topologically equivalent, really, and don't give a concrete approach for concrete metrics.

Comment: I got a bit curious with the following: How do we write the open sets of one of the topological spaces in terms of the other?

Comment: @RedBanana what do you mean? A set is open for $d$ iff it’s open for $d’$ so they’re exactly the same sets.